# SQL - Selecting max of indivdual field instead of all

Tags: sql, postgresql

Running a query which should return all open questions along with the last update time they were updated.

The way this works is a question is inserted into the Question table, and updates / answers are inserted to qUpdate table with a foreign key of the original question to associate them.

This is the query I've written at the moment however it's not quite what I want:

```
SELECT MAX (qUpdate.UpdateTime) AS LastUpdateTime, Question.ID FROM Question
LEFT JOIN qUpdate ON qID = qUpdate.qID WHERE Status = 'open'GROUP BY Question.ID, Question.Status;
```

The result:

```
     lastupdatetime     id
    2012-12-21 20:37:00;7
    2012-12-21 20:37:00;10
    2012-12-21 20:37:00;1000
    2012-12-21 20:37:00;5
    2012-12-21 20:37:00;2
    2012-12-21 20:37:00;9
```

As you can see it returns the latest update for all of the questions as oppose to the latest update for each of the questions. I understand why but I'm not sure how to solve this issue.

Sorry I was a bit ambiguous in my explanation..

Basically:

At present it returns the last update time regardless of what the update time of a particular question is i.e. it finds the maximum last update time for all of them and returns it for all the questions that are open...

What I'd like it to do is list all of the open questions as well as the last update time for that particular ticket.

**Im using Postgresql**

Comment: I really don't understand what difference you are implying between "all rows" and "each row". Don't those phrases basically mean the same thing?

Comment: Please explain better what do you want to achieve ... And post the schema of the two tables if possible .

Comment: What I mean is : Each question will have a different update time. And at the moment it is just treating the update time as one big field as oppose to selecting the max update time for each of the questions if that makes sense?

Comment: @Jimmy It would be easier to understand if you post your current data in tabular format and the expected result, instead of the result of the query that is not working.

Comment: @MostyMostacho Ok I'll bare that in mind when I next post. Apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is is your problem:

```
LEFT JOIN qUpdate ON qID = qUpdate.qID
```

Should be this:

```
LEFT JOIN qUpdate ON qID = Question.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  You don't need to group by the status.

```
SELECT MAX (qUpdate.UpdateTime) AS LastUpdateTime, Question.ID FROM Question
LEFT JOIN qUpdate ON qID = qUpdate.qID WHERE Status = 'open' GROUP BY Question.ID;
```